# Exception while implementing LazyModel for primefaces datalist

Tags: spring, jsf-2, primefaces, pagination, nullpointerexception

I am trying to implement the lazy loading model for the primefaces datalist similar to datatable as shown [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf).

My initial code with the normal AJAX pagination feature works absolutely fine. However, when I try using the lazy loading model, I get the exception below when the page loads :

```
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/pages/index.xhtml]
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.ArrayList$SubList
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doWriteState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:325)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.writeState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:173)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:418)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here's the code of **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/pages/templates/template.xhtml">
   <ui:define name="content">

      <h:form prependId="false" id="form">
         <p:dataList value="#{movies.lazyMovieModel}" var="movie" id="movies" paginator="true" rows="10"
            paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
            type="none" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" lazy="true">

            <h:outputText value="#{movie.movieName}, #{movie.releaseYear}" style="margin-left:10px">
            </h:outputText>
            <br/>
         </p:dataList>
      </h:form>

   </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

**MovieListBean.java**

```
import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;

import com.clixflix.enitities.Movie;
import com.clixflix.jsf.extensions.LazyMovieDataModel;

@ManagedBean(name = "movies")
@ViewScoped
public class MovieListBean extends BaseBean implements Serializable
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -5719443344065177588L;

   private LazyDataModel<Movie> lazyMovieModel;

   @PostConstruct
   public void initialize() {
      lazyMovieModel = new LazyMovieDataModel();
   }

   public LazyDataModel<Movie> getLazyMovieModel() 
   {
      List<Movie> movieList = getServiceLocator().getMovieService().getMovieList();
      ((LazyMovieDataModel) lazyMovieModel).setMovieList(movieList);
      return lazyMovieModel;
   }
}
```

**LazyMovieDataModel.java** (LazyModel implementation)

```
public class LazyMovieDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Movie>
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 8745562148994455749L;

   private List<Movie> movieList;

   public LazyMovieDataModel() {
      this.movieList = Collections.emptyList();
   }

   @Override
   public List<Movie> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
      // Sorting
      if (null != sortField) {
         LazySorter sorter = new LazySorter(sortField, sortOrder);
         Collections.sort(movieList, sorter);
         sorter = null;
      }

      // RowCount
      int rowCount = movieList.size();
      this.setRowCount(rowCount);

      // Pagination
      if (rowCount > pageSize) {
         return movieList.subList(first, (first + pageSize));
      }
      else {
         return movieList;
      }
   }


   private class LazySorter implements Comparator<Movie>
   {
      private String sortField;

      private SortOrder sortOrder;

      LazySorter(String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder) {
         this.sortField = sortField;
         this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      @Override
      public int compare(Movie movie1, Movie movie2) {
         Object value1 = null, value2 = null;

         try {
            value1 = Movie.class.getField(this.sortField).get(movie1);
            value2 = Movie.class.getField(this.sortField).get(movie2);

            int value = ((Comparable<Object>) value1).compareTo(value2);
            return SortOrder.ASCENDING.equals(sortOrder) ? value : -1 * value;
         }
         catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
         }
      }
   }

   public void setMovieList(List<Movie> movieList) {
      this.movieList = movieList;
   }
}
```

I am assuming the exception is at this line:

```
return movieList.subList(first, (first + pageSize));
```

Could anyone please guide me as to what am I missing?

Also, I observe in the logs, that when I use the lazymodel, the DB gets queried **three times** but when I use the normal AJAX pagination, the DB is queried **only once** :|

---

**UPDATE**: I figured out the reason for the DB being queried 3 times. It was because I was calling my service in the getter of the LazyModel instead of only in the load method.

I made the following changes in the classes:

**LazyMovieDataModel.java**

```
public class LazyMovieDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Movie>
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 8745562148994455749L;

   public LazyMovieDataModel() {}

   @Override
   public List<Movie> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {

      List<Movie> movieList = getServiceLocator().getMovieService().getMovieList(first, (first + pageSize));

      // RowCount
      int rowCount = ((Number)getServiceLocator().getMovieService().getMovieCount()).intValue();
      this.setRowCount(rowCount);
   }
}
```

**LazyModel getter in MovieListBean.java**

```
/* Removed PostConstruct init method */

public LazyDataModel<Movie> getLazyMovieModel() 
{
   return lazyMovieModel;
}
```

The above changes work fine on the initial page load. However, when I hit the next page button (or any pagination button) I get an NPE for `getServiceLocator()` in the load method.

The serviceLocator is a `protected` access modified managed property inherited from BaseBean and injected using Spring.

Any reason why the getter returns null on subsequent invokes ???

Comment: Is `Movie` serializable?

Comment: As a workaround you should be able to get rid of the exception by setting your `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` to `SERVER`.

Comment: @kolossus: Thanks for the reply. I was able to prevent the exception by making the changes as mentioned in my update. But I seem to get an NPE. I think this has something to do with serialization too. Could you please have a look ??

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList$SubList is a problem.  The subList returned does not implement serializable.
Try using:

```
return new ArrayList(movieList.subList(first, (first + pageSize)));
```

Comment: After all, the whole design is simply flawed. OP should never be performing business logic in getter methods and never be using `List#sublist()` and never be holding that as an instance variable of `LazyDataModel`. The business service method should immediately return exactly the requested records based on the supplied parameters, otherwise the whole lazy loading idea is completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892496/primefaces-lazy-loading-is-not-implemented/16892587).There are 2 load methods in LazyDataModel:

```
public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Lazy loading is not implemented.");
}

public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta,Map<String,String> filters) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Lazy loading is not implemented.");
}
```

This is where the error is thrown. You are using multisort, so you should override the second.Default method is the first one.